# Uber API Integration-scopes

Tags: uber-api

I just created a developer account and my app on the Uber Developer Dashboard. For some reason, I can't set the scope for my tokens. It says I should contact Uber Business Development or Uber POC.

I tried using the scope in CURL, but it still doesn't let me get the profile of the user.

Comment: I have the same issue, were you able to get access to scope(s)?

Comment: Do you have any news?

Comment: Did you find any solutions?